# How to remove first character each td tag in the table and then show it with Google Chart API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

My current row in the table here is:

> Sales |   Sales   | 1000 |    1170 |  660 |   980 |   1200 |  1000

However, when I change this to:

> Sales |   Sales   | $1000 |   $1170 | $660 |  $980 |  $1200 | $1000

According to the changes above, the chart doesn't work anymore with that line. Hence, I would like to remove the first character as `$` in order to make that row returns all values to the first *blockquote*.

**<kbd>[Original demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/y7q65/1/)</kbd>** - Go with first Blockquote

**<kbd>[Changed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/y7q65/2/)</kbd>** - Go with second Blockquote

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="align-content: center"></div>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Title1</td>
    <td>Title2</td>
    <td>Title3</td>
    <td>Title4</td>
    <td>Title5</td>
    <td>Title6</td>
    <td>Title7</td>
    <td>Title8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Year</td>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Year</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2004</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2005</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2006</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2007</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2008</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2009</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Sales</td>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Sales</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">$1000</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">$1170</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">$660</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">$980</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">$1200</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">$1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Expenses</td>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Expenses</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">400.5</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">460</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">1120</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">1220</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">1180</td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">740</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Get data from ? column?
var from_column = 0;
// Get data to ? column?
var to_column = 6;


var FChartValue1 = new Array();
var FChartName = new Array();


$("document").ready(function () {

    var Coords1 = new Array();
    var Coords2 = new Array();
    var Labels = new Array();

    var vertical_axis = "2,3";
    vertical_axis = vertical_axis.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < vertical_axis.length; i++) {
        Coords1 = getCoords(vertical_axis[0]); // Display Vertical Axis in the row "2"
        Coords2 = getCoords(vertical_axis[1]); // Display Vertical Axis in the row "3"
    }

    function getCoords(vertical_axis) {
        var Coords = [];
        var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')").eq(1).closest('table').find('tr');
        var arrayList1_temp;
        $(arrayList1).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb-title').eq(0).text() != "") {
                if (arrayList1_temp) {
                    arrayList1_temp = arrayList1_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb-title').eq(1).closest('table').find('tr').eq(vertical_axis).find('td').not(".ms-vb-title").slice(from_column, to_column));
                }
                else {
                    arrayList1_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb-title').eq(1).closest('table').find('tr').eq(vertical_axis).find('td').not(".ms-vb-title").slice(from_column, to_column);
                }
            }
        });
        $.each(arrayList1_temp, function (i, e) {
            Coords[i] = $(e).text();
        });
        return Coords;
    }


    var temp = "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun";
    temp = temp.split(",");
    $.each(temp, function (i) {
        Labels[i] = temp[i];
    });

    FChartValue1 = Coords1; // Display value in the column "1" to the Chart
    FChartValue2 = Coords2; // Display value in the column "2" to the Chart
    FChartName = Labels;
});


//Graph Rendering
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales'); // Annotate P2
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses'); // Annotate P3

    data.addRows(FChartValue1.length);

    for (i = 0; i < FChartValue1.length; i++) {
        data.setValue(i, 0, FChartName[i]);
        data.setValue(i, 1, parseFloat(FChartValue1[i]));
        data.setValue(i, 2, parseFloat(FChartValue2[i]));
        //data.setValue(i, 2, parseInt(FChartValue2[i])); // Second column Chart
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        title: 'Report for Electric Energy Consumption', // Title for the Chart
        width: 1000, height: 400, is3D: false,
        hAxis: { title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontName: 'Tahoma', italic: false } }, // Title for Horizontal Axis
        vAxis: { title: "kW", titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontName: 'Tahoma', italic: false } }, // Title for Vertical Axis
    }
    );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a string replace on the value.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7q65/3/

```
        data.setValue(i, 1, parseFloat(FChartValue1[i].replace('$', '')));
```